# Await axios request in method is not finished in time

Tags: vue.js, async-await, axios

In my component I have a few api-calls that rely on each other:

```
async mounted() {
    // Call 1
    await axios.get('/api/users/' + userId).then(response => {
      this.dataNeeded = response.data
    })

    // Call 2
    axios.get('/api/somethingelse').then(response => {
      this.dataNeeded[response.data[0]] // <-- need to fetch this.dataNeeded 
    })
 }
```

And this works!

However... I want to move the function (the call 1) to a method to repeatedly call it and use:

```
methods: {
    axiosCall1: async function() {
    axios.get('/api/users/' + userId).then(response => {
      this.dataNeeded = response.data
    })
}

await this.axiosCall1();
// axiosCall2 should now be able to use this.dataNeeded. 
// However this.dataNeeded is now: {__ob__: Observer}
// And not an object {} with data
this.axiosCall2();
```

Can any1 spot what might go wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are `await`ing in the wrong place. You should `await` on the asynchronous operation (in our case `axios.get()`)

> await blocks the code execution within the async function

Try this

```
methods: {
  axiosCall1: async function() {
    await axios.get('/api/users/' + userId).then(response => {
      this.dataNeeded = response.data
    })
  },
  ...
}
```

And then

```
this.axiosCall1();
// axiosCall2 should now be able to use this.dataNeeded. 
// And this.dataNeeded is now: an object {} with data
this.axiosCall2();
```

Comment: Oh makes sense. Will try when I’m back home.

Comment: Thank you! This worked but with a minor caveat. I had to use await in front of this.axiosCall1() too.

Comment: @anton-vbr Glad it helped. Your `mounted` function doesn't need to be an `async` function. get rid of that `async` in front of `mounted` and also the `await` in front of `this.axiosCall...`